# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting from USB

Tags: uefi, live-usb, dd, unetbootin

I tried to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu 16.04. When booting from the USB I only see a black screen with a blinking cursor though.

Here are the different attempts I've tried:

- Download the Ubuntu .iso and validate the MD5 hash
- Create partition table gpt (and msdos in another attempt) with `gparted`  with FAT32 formatting afterwards
- First attempt was to install the downloaded .iso with `unetbootin` which completed correctly but the USB didn't boot, only black screen with the cursor
- Next attempt was to use `dd` with the command `sudo dd bs=4M status=progress if=ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc1`
  But when booting now I get the same results as above

Both, unetbootin and dd, were tried with gpt and msdos partition tables and FAT32.
I'm using a Thinkpad E540 with UEFI.

Comment: Try the `dd` command again, but specify `/dev/sdc`, not `/dev/sdc1`, as the `of=` option.

Comment: Awesome, thx man it worked! If you put it in an answer I'll give you a thumbs up and close it

Comment: Using `dd` with `/dev/sdb` is what worked for me as well. Thanks @RodSmith!